Мне хочется сделать телеграм-бота для того, чтобы он одногруппникам и мне присылал расписание, рейтинг, домашки. Но как мне брать данные без доступа?
Мне хочется сделать телеграм-бота для того, чтобы он одногруппникам и мне присылал расписание, рейтинг, домашки. Но как мне брать данные без доступа? Дело вот в чем, рейтинг выставляется учителями, соответственно мне не доверят доступ к Google-таблице. Но можно ли их как-то копировать себе, то есть обновлять скаченную на мой диск, с которой я уже могу работать?

определитесь, у вас вопрос по в итоге по телеграм-боту или по гугл таблицам?

Если знаете URL таблицы IMPORTRANGE вам в помощь, но не уверен, что с доступами не будет проблем

Решил: библиотека gspread легко позволяет это сделать, просто после настройки бота в гугл-таблице пригласите его по почте, и он сможет брать данные!
